# Edit Project directly from remote server

Tags: ftp, sublime-text-2, phpstorm, coda

I am currently working with PHP/HTML on a remote server via PHPStorm. I love how intelligent it is, but i dont like how it forces me to have a local project and that i have to sync it.

Is it any way to work like in Coda2 and Sublime Text with pure remote access, but with the same intelligent system as PHPStorm has?

Answer (score 1):

Not currently supported. Please vote for [WI-1398](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-1398)

Answer (score 0):

Please refer my tutorial which explains how to access remote files using ftp . We can edit the files and automatically upload the files to the server on save.

http://www.pearlbells.co.uk/edit-remote-files-phpstorm/

Main steps :

- Select File->New project from Existing files
- Select the checkbox as shown in fig (refer blog for images) and click next.
- Enter projectname
- From the dropdown select ‘On explicit save atcion’
- Add new remote server
- Enter Ftp details
- select the remote path.

Refer the tutorial for demo images and explanation.

Comment: Hi Liz, please take a look [here, refering your other answers on diffent sites](http://superuser.com/help/promotion)